full load & ongoing changes are not getting replicated for a partitioned table in postgres in aws dms
I am trying to use AWS DMS for full load and ongoing changes where both the source and target tables are partitioned for postgres db. The target table preparation mode is do nothing with validation with full migration.
The full load happened successfully but since then the ongoing changes are not getting migrated.
I am not seeing any error logs
I also see that the dashboard says no primary key in validation state. Is it because DMS is unable to find a primary key, its not able to replicate ongoing changes?
In that case, how do I enable primary key for the partitioned table as I can see that the target table has a unique key consisting of 2 columns but still DMS is not able to recognize it.
For other non-partitioned tables, DMS is able to identify the primary key.

Perhaps the PK discussion in this document may help. Question, why would you not want a PK on your partitioned table? You can have a clustered index aligned with the partition while also having a non-clustered primary key that uniquely identifies a record in the table. -->https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html
